# jquery fullpage vertical and horizontal scrolling

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling, fullpage.js

I am trying to make with jquery fullpage vertical and horizontal scroll. For example, first it will scroll vertical if section don't have slide in it, and if section have slides in it, it will scroll horizontal until last slide and than scroll vertical again to next section? Something similar to this: http://www.mi.com/shouhuan/#home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fullPage.js provides [an extension for that called "Scroll Horizontally"](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scroll-horizontally.html).